# Cucumber import

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit

[image]

in the testRunner file, I cannot import @RunWith(Cucumber.class) i have been watching many youtube videos everyone is saying sometimes we have to write down the import manually, even though I have written import manually which is **import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;** it is showing an error

[image]

Comment: You might need to add a dependency to [cucumber-junit](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit) to your project.

Comment: I have added it already

Comment: Then you should provide a bit more about your code structure, project information (Maven dependencies or similar). But please post text not images.

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using? (Is it the same version as used in whichever videos/tutorials you are using?) Are you sure you have downloaded the dependencies already?